# Entity Framework database creation C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm having a bit of trouble getting my code to create a database using Entity Framework. Not sure how or why, but I think I'm missing something.

SecurityDataLayer.cs

```
namespace SecurityDoorDatabase.DBConnection
{
    class SecurityDataLayer
    {
        public class SecurityDoorDBContext : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<Person> Perons { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Door> Doors { get; set; }
            public DbSet<DoorSecurity> DoorSecurities { get; set; }
            public DbSet<SecurityInput> SecurityInputs { get; set; }
            public DbSet<SecurityLevel> SecurityLevels { get; set; }
            public DbSet<SecurityCards> SecurityCard { get; set; }
            public DbSet<FingerPrints> FingerPrint { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Example of one of the many CS files I'm using.

```
class SecurityCards
{
    int securityCardID;
    int securityCardScan;

    public int SecurityCardID { get => securityCardID; set => securityCardID = value; }
    public int SecurityCardScan { get => securityCardScan; set => securityCardScan = value; }

    public SecurityCards(int securityCardID, int securityCardScan)
    {
        SecurityCardID = securityCardID;
        SecurityCardScan = securityCardScan;
    }
}
```

The usings for every CS file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
```

Program.CS

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Employee dingleberrySmith = new Employee(0, "Dingleberry", "Smithson", "Smith", 0, "IT Tech",
            new FingerPrints(0,134), new SecurityCards(0,134), new SecurityLevel(4, 7));
        Employee narsetSarkhan = new Employee(0, "Narset", "", "Sarkhan", 0, "Secretary",
            new FingerPrints(0, 0), new SecurityCards(0, 0), new SecurityLevel(1, 1));

        Door door597 = new Door(598, 597, "Fifth Floor", 598, 7, 7, "Door Code", "Security Card", "Finger Print");
        Door door227 = new Door(228, 227, "Second Floor", 228, 2, 2, "Door Code", "Security Card", "Finger Print");
        Door doorEntrance = new Door(0, 0, "Lobby", 0, 0, 0, "", "", "");
        CanEmployeeGoThroughDoor(dingleberrySmith, door227);
        CanEmployeeGoThroughDoor(dingleberrySmith, door597);
        CanEmployeeGoThroughDoor(narsetSarkhan, door597);
        CanEmployeeGoThroughDoor(narsetSarkhan, doorEntrance);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void CanEmployeeGoThroughDoor(Employee employee, Door door)
    {
        if ((employee.EmployeeSecurityLevel.SecurityLevelID >= door.SecurityLevelID) ||(employee.EmployeeSecurityLevel.SecurityLevelID >= door.SecurityLevelID && employee.EmployeeFingerPrint.FingerPrintScan > 0 && door.SecurityInputTertiary == "Finger Print" && employee.EmployeeSecurityCard.SecurityCardScan > 0 && door.SecurityInputSecondary == "Security Card") || (employee.EmployeeSecurityLevel.SecurityLevelID >= door.SecurityLevelID&& employee.EmployeeSecurityCard.SecurityCardScan > 0 && door.SecurityInputSecondary == "Security Card") || (employee.EmployeeSecurityLevel.SecurityLevelID >= door.SecurityLevelID && employee.EmployeeFingerPrint.FingerPrintScan > 0 && door.SecurityInputTertiary == "Finger Print"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Access Granted");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Access Denied");
        }
    }
}
```

If someone could help me figure out how to make the database connections and where to put them, that'd be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add connection string to app.config file or web.config file. I will explain for app.config file and for EF code first.

Add this into `<configuration>` on app.config file.

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="ConnectionStringName" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog=DbName; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

And your SecurityDataLayer.cs should be like:

```
namespace SecurityDoorDatabase.DBConnection
{
    class SecurityDataLayer
    {
        public class SecurityDoorDBContext : DbContext
        {
            public SecurityDoorDBContext() : base("name=ConnectionStringName")
            {
            }

            public DbSet<Person> Perons { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Door> Doors { get; set; }
            public DbSet<DoorSecurity> DoorSecurities { get; set; }
            public DbSet<SecurityInput> SecurityInputs { get; set; }
            public DbSet<SecurityLevel> SecurityLevels { get; set; }
            public DbSet<SecurityCards> SecurityCard { get; set; }
            public DbSet<FingerPrints> FingerPrint { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```